# Error: 4 DEADLINE_EXCEEDED: Deadline exceeded on CloudRUN

Tags: node.js, async-await, google-cloud-run, google-secret-manager

I got google express app which deployed in Google CloudRun.
I would like to use some shared data which relevant to all users and loading it to global parameters.
My code is using google secret manager to retrieve some database connection info for retrieving data into global parameters.
When the app is cold, the first user gets error message but initiates async function which loading the data into global parameters, eventually the next calls will be served correctly.
Everything is working fine buy recently I noticed an error when trying to connect to Google secret manager:

```
Error: 4 DEADLINE_EXCEEDED: Deadline exceeded
    at Object.callErrorFromStatus (/usr/src/app/node_modules/@google-cloud/secret-manager/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call.js:30:26)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (/usr/src/app/node_modules/@google-cloud/secret-manager/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client.js:175:52)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (/usr/src/app/node_modules/@google-cloud/secret-manager/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client-interceptors.js:341:141)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (/usr/src/app/node_modules/@google-cloud/secret-manager/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client-interceptors.js:304:181)
    at Http2CallStream.outputStatus (/usr/src/app/node_modules/@google-cloud/secret-manager/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call-stream.js:116:74)
    at Http2CallStream.maybeOutputStatus (/usr/src/app/node_modules/@google-cloud/secret-manager/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call-stream.js:155:22)
    at Http2CallStream.endCall (/usr/src/app/node_modules/@google-cloud/secret-manager/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call-stream.js:141:18)
    at Http2CallStream.cancelWithStatus (/usr/src/app/node_modules/@google-cloud/secret-manager/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call-stream.js:457:14)
    at Timeout.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/node_modules/@google-cloud/secret-manager/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/deadline-filter.js:59:28)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:554:17) {
```

My code is something like that:

```
const { SecretManagerServiceClient } = require('@google-cloud/secret-manager');
const smClient = new SecretManagerServiceClient();

const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
let jsonParser = bodyParser.json()
const pkg = require('./package');

// ============== Express App  ========
const app = express();
// Serve the files in /assets at the URI /assets
app.use('/assets', express.static('assets'));

//Params
global.Param1 = null;
global.Param2 = null;

let PgPwd = null;


app.post('/Test', jsonParser, async (req, res) => {

    try 
    {
        loadParams();
        common.errors_client.report("Params were not loaded");
        throw new Error("Params were not loaded");
    }
    catch (err) {
        return res.status(400);
    }
}

async function loadParams() {

  try {
    const promise1 = loadDataFromPostgresqlToParam1();
    const promise2 = loadDataFromPostgresqlToParam2();

    await Promise.all([promise1, promise2]);
  }
  catch (err) {
    throw new Error(err);
  }
}


async function loadDataFromPostgresqlToParam1() {
  try {
    //=============== PostgresSQL ==================
    let pg_client = await getPgClient();
    await pg_client.connect()
    const resPg = await pg_client.query('select * from tabel1');
    await pg_client.end()
    let Param1 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(resPg));
  }
}


async function loadDataFromPostgresqlToParam2() {
  try {
    //=============== PostgresSQL ==================
    let pg_client = await getPgClient();
    await pg_client.connect()
    const resPg = await pg_client.query('select * from tabel2');
    await pg_client.end()
    let Param2 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(resPg));
  }
}

async function getPgClient() {
  var ret_client;
  if (PgPwd == null) {
    await getSecret().then((localPwd) => {
      PgPwd = localPwd; // assign to global variable
    })
  };
  ret_client = new Client({
    user: process.env.pgUser,
    host: process.env.pgHost,
    database: process.env.pgDataBase,
    password: PgPwd,
    port: process.env.pgPort
  });

  return ret_client;
}

async function getSecret() {

  const [version] = await smClient.accessSecretVersion({
    name: process.env.pgpwdlocation
  });
  const pwd = version.payload.data.toString();
  return pwd;
}
```

Not sure what could be the reason for that.
The error is not consistent.

Comment: Are you libraries up to date?

Comment: This is a known error, please see this post, and please try to provide a lot of details to the  google engineers https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-tasks/issues/397#issuecomment-671476201